# Conditional Format in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I am trying to applying Conditional Formatting for a column deepening on the values of other columns.

This is the formula for conditional format. And this is applied to `$U$2`

`=AND($T$2="PCT",$U$2<>100)`

I want to copy the similar formula and logic for rest of cells in Column `U2`. When i drag the format on `U2`, this will apply for `$U$12:$U$16` but the formula still refers to Row2.

Is there any way so I can apply this for other columns easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use mixed references (without `$` before `2`) if you need allow the row to change

```
=AND($T2="PCT",$U2<>100)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. The formula would be right. But the applies will be updated to =$U$2:$U$30 when i drag or copy format down the row. I want the respective formula to be applied only for that particular cell and not for the entire range.

Comment: If you apply CF `=AND($T2="PCT",$U2<>100)` to range `$U$2:$U$30`, you will get `=AND($T2="PCT",$U2<>100)` for $U$2, `=AND($T3="PCT",$U3<>100)` for $U$3 and so on. What do you mean saying `I want the respective formula to be applied only for that particular cell`?